# Discord card collection bot : Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

basically im trying to make a discord card collection bot, so i have this one command where it goes in database and pick 3 random cards to drop but it give me this error :

``

```
  File "d:\rococo-2.0\core.py", line 440, in dropcard
    cardNames = await query(f"SELECT cardname FROM Cards WHERE filename = '{cardsToDrop[0]}' OR filename = '{cardsToDrop[1]}' OR filename = '{cardsToDrop[2]}'", cardDBCommand) #get the names of the cards to drop
                                                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\rococo-2.0\ven\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "d:\rococo-2.0\ven\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\rococo-2.0\ven\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
here is the drop command block:
```

```
@bot.command(aliases = ["D", "d", "drop"])
async def dropcard(ctx):
    dropTimeStr = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    userList = await query("SELECT userid FROM Users", userDBCommand)
    lastDrop = datetime.strptime("00:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")
    message = str()

    if userList == None: 
        await query(f"INSERT INTO Users (userid, username, lastdrop) VALUES ({ctx.author.id}, '{ctx.author.name}', '{dropTimeStr}')", userDBCommand, ctx)
    elif str(ctx.author.id) not in userList:
        await query(f"INSERT INTO Users (userid, username, lastdrop) VALUES ({ctx.author.id}, '{ctx.author.name}', '{dropTimeStr}')", userDBCommand, ctx)
    elif str(ctx.author.id) in userList and await query(f"SELECT lastdrop FROM Users WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}", userDBCommand, ctx) == None:
        await query(f"UPDATE Users SET lastgrab = '{dropTimeStr}' WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}", userDBCommand, ctx)
    elif str(ctx.author.id) in userList and str(ctx.author.id) != botAdminId:
        lastDrop = datetime.strptime(await query(f"SELECT lastdrop FROM Users WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}", userDBCommand, ctx), "%H:%M:%S")

    if (datetime.strptime(dropTimeStr, "%H:%M:%S") - lastDrop).seconds < 300 and str(ctx.author.id) != botAdminId:
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention + ", you can drop a card only every 5 minutes.", delete_after = 60)
        return
    else:
        await query(f"UPDATE Users SET lastdrop = '{dropTimeStr}' WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}", userDBCommand) #update last drop time
    
    cardPathList = await query("SELECT filename FROM Cards ORDER BY cardname", cardDBCommand) #get all cards
    cardRarity = await query("SELECT rarity FROM Cards ORDER BY cardname", cardDBCommand) #list of rarities
    while True:
        cardsToDrop = random.choices(cardPathList, cardRarity) #k = 3
        if set(cardsToDrop).__len__() == cardsToDrop.__len__(): break #if there are no duplicates, break the loop
    cardNames = await query(f"SELECT cardname FROM Cards WHERE filename = '{cardsToDrop[0]}' OR filename = '{cardsToDrop[1]}' OR filename = '{cardsToDrop[2]}'", cardDBCommand) #get the names of the cards to drop
    imageCreation(cardsToDrop, GREY, os.path.abspath("Temp/drop.png")) #create the image
```

``

Can someone help me with that error ?
tell me if needed more info about my code, new to stackoverflow

I tried to change the name of the files, even changing the name of files in the sql request but its still showing me the same error

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying to access an index which doesn't exist, make sure you have three elements exist in cardsToDrop list object otherwise, it'll throw IndexOutOfRange for sure.